# How to use Ubuntu disk on Mac

Tags: installation, mac

How do I use the DVD I burned to Run Ubuntu on Mac 10.6.8? Tried "C", then "option" at restart and DVD is ejected. I want to Run, to take a look, before I install.

Comment: You should specify what Macbook your using..

Answer (score 1):

Install `refit` boot manager, then it will be easier to install as when the Mac boots it will then wait and allow you to select the DVD to install from. If it doesn't run then you know that the DVD you created is not made correctly.

http://refit.sourceforge.net/#download

Although this link says its out of date, its still valid and the alternative refind is harder to install. So if you are experienced you could install that instead. But if you are a beginner then I recommend you install refit instead.

PS: When you install refit, reboot the Mac at least twice as it takes two boots to install correctly